# Kotlin: generics and variance

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, covariance

I want to create an extension function on `Throwable` that, given a `KClass`, recursively searches for a root cause that matches the argument. The following is one attempt that works:

```
fun <T : Throwable> Throwable.getCauseIfAssignableFrom(e: KClass<T>): Throwable? = when {
    this::class.java.isAssignableFrom(e.java) -> this
    nonNull(this.cause) -> this.cause?.getCauseIfAssignableFrom(e)
    else -> null
}
```

This works too:

```
fun Throwable.getCauseIfAssignableFrom(e: KClass<out Throwable>): Throwable? = when {
    this::class.java.isAssignableFrom(e.java) -> this
    nonNull(this.cause) -> this.cause?.getCauseIfAssignableFrom(e)
    else -> null
}
```

I call the function like so: `e.getCauseIfAssignableFrom(NoRemoteRepositoryException::class)`.

However, [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) about generics says:

> This is called declaration-site variance: we can annotate the type
>   parameter T of Source to make sure that it is only returned (produced)
>   from members of Source, and never consumed. To do this we provide
>   the out modifier

```
abstract class Source<out T> {
    abstract fun nextT(): T
}

fun demo(strs: Source<String>) {
    val objects: Source<Any> = strs // This is OK, since T is an out-parameter
    // ...
}
```

In my case, parameter `e` isn't returned, but consumed. It seems to me that it should be declared as `e: KClass<in Throwable>` but that doesn't compile. However, if I think of `out` as "you can only read from, or return, it" and `in` as "you can only write, or assign a value, to it", then it makes sense. Can someone explain?

Comment: Hey, just noticed your recursive function is a prime candidate for a sequence: `generateSequence(this) { it.cause }.first { it::class.java.isAssignableFrom(e.java) }` should be behaviour compatible, is IMO faster to consume mentally and also gets rid of recursion. Don't edit the question though, as it might invalidate the current answer.

Comment: You are calling with your method with a derived class of Throwable, so when you define the parameter as KClass<in Throwable>, you should expect a compile error, right?

Comment: @mEQ5aNLrK3lqs3kfSa5HbvsTWe0nIu Some username! Regarding the sequence, the problem I see is that all cause are collected first, and then the matching one, if any, is returned. But there is no need to iterate any more if we find a match; your claim that sequence is faster than recursion doesn't seem to hold theoretically.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar `Sequence` is lazy, it does not continue iterating.

Comment: Verified that the sequence is indeed lazily evaluated by writing a test. Thanks.

Comment: As @ephemient stated, sequences are lazy (I suggest getting familiar with the actual source code of sequences, there are a lot of gotcha's!), and I never claimed performance gains - I think it just reads nicer given understanding of generated sequences. And why yes, some username ;)

Comment: @mEQ5aNLrK3lqs3kfSa5HbvsTWe0nIu Sorry, I misread "IMO faster to consume mentally" as just "faster".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you don't actually use the variance of the type parameter: you never pass a value or use a value returned from a call to your `e: KClass<T>`.

The variance describes which values you can pass as an argument and what you can expect from the values returned from properties and functions when you work with the projected type (e.g. inside a function implementation). For example, where a `KClass<T>` would return a `T` (as written in the signature), a `KClass<out SomeType>` can return either `SomeType` *or any of its subtypes*. On contrary, where a `KClass<T>` would expect an argument of `T`, a `KClass<in SomeType>` expects *some of the supertypes* of `SomeType` (but it is unknown which exactly).

This, in fact, defines the limitations on the actual type arguments of the instances that you pass to such a function. With invariant type `KClass<Base>`, you cannot pass a `KClass<Super>` or `KClass<Derived>` (where `Derived : Base : Super`). But if a function expects `KClass<out Base>`, then you can also pass a `KClass<Derived>`, because it satisfies the aforementioned requirement: it returns `Derived` from its methods which should return `Base` or its subtype (but that's not true for `KClass<Super>`). And, on contrary, a function that expects `KClass<in Base>` can also receive `KClass<Super>`

So, when you rewrite `getCauseIfAssignableFrom` to accept a `e: KClass<in Throwable>`, you state that in the implementation you want to be able to pass a `Throwable` to some generic function or a property of `e`, and you need a `KClass` instance that is capable of handling that. The `Any::class` or `Throwable::class` would fit, but that's not what you need.

Since you don't call any of `e`'s functions and don't access any of its properties, you could even make its type `KClass<*>` (clearly stating that you don't care what is the type and allow it to be anything), and it would work.

But your use case requires you to restrict the type to be a subtype of `Throwable`. This is where `KClass<out Throwable>` works: it restricts the type argument to be a subtype of `Throwable` (again, you state that, for the functions and properties of `KClass<T>` that return `T` or something with `T` like `Function<T>`, you want to use the return value as if `T` is a subtype of `Throwable`; though you don't do it).

The other option that works for you is defining an upper bound `<T : Throwable>`. This is similar to `<out Throwable>`, but it additionally captures the type argument of `KClass<T>` and allows you to use it somewhere else in the signature (in the return type or the types of the other parameters) or inside the implementation.

Comment: I read your explanation 3 times and what you say is true, but I'm not sure it answers my question. As you said I don't use any properties or methods from `e`, except getting the java class. It seems like `in` should work too, but it doesn't. Can you help me understand why not?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, that's because when you define an argument of type `KClass<in Throwable>` you restrict the arguments that you can pass so that they should all be able to receive a `Throwable` where a `KClass<T>` expects `T` (you want to be able to pass a `Throwable` **in**). For example, `Any::class` safisfies this restriction: since it can receive `Any` as `T`, it can receive `Throwable` as well. But `NoRemoteRepositoryException::class` does not: it expects only `NoRemoteRepositoryException` and its subtypes as `T`, so it would not know what to do with an arbitrary `Throwable`.

Comment: The verbosity of your answer was actually a hindrance to my understanding :) I prefer short and to-the-point answers. But I understand each person has their own way of explaining, and understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have addressed why you don't need variance at this **use** site.

FYI, the API would be more usable if you cast the return to the expected type,

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T : Any> Throwable.getCauseIfInstance(e: KClass<T>): T? = when {
    e.java.isAssignableFrom(javaClass) -> this as T
    else -> cause?.getCauseIfInstance(e)
}
```

but it's more Kotlin-like to use a reified type.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Throwable.getCauseIfInstance(): T? =
    generateSequence(this) { it.cause }.filterIsInstance<T>().firstOrNull()
```

This is effectively the same as writing an explicit loop, but shorter.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Throwable.getCauseIfInstance(): T? {
    var current = this
    while (true) {
        when (current) {
            is T -> return current
            else -> current = current.cause ?: return null
        }
    }
}
```

And unlike the original, this method does not require `kotlin-reflect`.

(I've also changed the behavior from `isAssignableFrom` to `is` (`instanceof`); I have a hard time imagining how the original could have been useful.)

Comment: For inline functions with reified type parameters and no higher order function parameters, it may be preferable to extract the logic into a non-inline function taking an additional Java `Class`, then making the inliine function simply call that function. This would prevent bytecode explosion if the function logic grows and is used from many places.

Comment: Where is the `e` formal parameter in your implementation?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar It is not necessary. When you write `.getCauseIfInstance<T>()` the compiler fills in the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you cite from documentation, you are showing a generic **class** with the `out` annotation.  This annotation give users of the class a guarantee that the class will not put out anything but a T or class derived from T.

In you code example, you are showing a generic function **parameter** with an `out` annotation on the parameter's type.  This is giving users of the parameter the guarantee that the parameter will not be anything but a `T` (in your case a `KClass<Throwable>`) or a class derived from `T` (a `KClass<{derived from Throwable}>`).

Now reverse the thinking for `in`.  If you were to use `e: KClass<in Throwable>` then you constrain the parameter to supers of `Throwable`.

In the case of your compiler error, it isn't the point whether or not your function uses methods or properties of `e`.  In your case, the declaration of the parameter is constraining how the function can be called, not how the function itself uses the parameter.  Therefore, using `in` instead of `out` disqualifies your call to the function with the parameter `NorRemoteRepositoryException::class`.

Of course, the constraints also apply within your function, but those constraints are never exercised because `e` is not used that way.